# Get array from model to view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, view, model, razor

In my model I have one int object and a boolean array:

```
public class mymodel
{
  public int Round { get; set; }
  public Boolean[] lstLabs { get; set; }
}
```

In my view I write this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var objModel = {  
    Round:"@Model.Round",
    lstLabs: "@Model.lstLabs"
      }; 
</script>
```

I get only the value of Round (the int object) , but I can't get the array , I just get this : lstLabs : System.Boolean[] , I tried : `lstLabs: @Model.lstLabs.slice()` but it didn't work , I got the same thing...

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want all properties of the view model:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var objModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    alert(objModel.Round + ' ' + objModel.lstLabs.length);
</script>
```

or if you want only a subset:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var objModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new {
        Labs = Model.lstLabs
    }));
    alert(objModel.Labs.length);
</script>
```